# How to script stap (systemtap) to see if some process has called specific kernel function?

Tags: linux, process, kernel, system, tap

Using stap, I can write *.stp file to

Either track a process's action like:

```
probe process("mytest").begin
{
    printf("Caught mytest process")
}
```

Or to track if a kernel function is called by any process:

```
probe kernel.function("do_exit").call #all processes
{
    printf("called kernel/exit.c: do_exit\n")
}
```

But my requirement is: to track the kernel function call from specific process names, like tracking "sys_open" called by "mytest" processes.

How to write this .stp statement/function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that: use a variable indicating the program name

```
global prog_name = "mytest";
probe kernel.function("do_exit").call
{
   if(execname() == progname){
        printf("called kernel/exit.c: do_exit\n");     
   }

}
```